# How to verify code from "Sign In with Apple"?

Tags: php, jwt, apple-sign-in

I'm trying to verify the code I got from the "Sign In with Apple" service on my Redirect Uri. I used the information from the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/signinwithapplerestapi/generate_and_validate_tokens) to create the post data and generate the "client_secret".

The response I'm getting is: `{"error":"invalid_client"}`.

My functions to generate the "client_secret" can be found below:

```php
function encode($data) {
    $encoded = strtr(base64_encode($data), '+/', '-_');
    return rtrim($encoded, '=');
}

function generateJWT($kid, $iss, $sub, $key) {
    $header = [
        'alg' => 'ES256',
        'kid' => $kid
    ];
    $body = [
        'iss' => $iss,
        'iat' => time(),
        'exp' => time() + 3600,
        'aud' => 'https://appleid.apple.com',
        'sub' => $sub
    ];

    $privKey = openssl_pkey_get_private($key);
    if (!$privKey) return false;

    $payload = encode(json_encode($header)).'.'.encode(json_encode($body));
    $signature = '';
    $success = openssl_sign($payloads, $signature, $privKey, OPENSSL_ALGO_SHA256);
    if (!$success) return false;

    return $payload.'.'.encode($signature);
}
```

My variables in this example:

**$kid** is my identifier for my private key. In this example it is JYJ5GS7N9K. I got the identifier from here https://developer.apple.com/account/resources/authkeys/list

**$iss** is my team identifier from my developer account. In this example it is WGL33ABCD6.

**$sub** is the same value as "client_id". My "client_id" in this example is "dev.hanashi.sign-in-with-apple". I got the client id from the app identifiers here: https://developer.apple.com/account/resources/identifiers/list

**$key** is my generated private key by developer account. The key has format like this:

```
-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----
myrandomgeneratedkeybyappledeveloperaccount
-----END PRIVATE KEY-----
```

This is the php code to make the request:

```php
$key = <<<EOD
-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----
myrandomgeneratedkeybyappledeveloperaccount
-----END PRIVATE KEY-----
EOD; // replaced with correct key

$kid = 'JYJ5GS7N9K'; // identifier for private key
$iss = 'WGL33ABCD6'; // team identifier
$sub = 'dev.hanashi.sign-in-with-apple'; // my app id

$jwt = generateJWT($kid, $iss, $sub, $key);

$data = [
    'client_id' => $sub,
    'client_secret' => $jwt,
    'code' => $_POST['code'],
    'grant_type' => 'authorization_code',
    'request_uri' => 'https://myurl.tld/redirect.php'
];
$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://appleid.apple.com/auth/token');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($data));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2) AppleWebKit/536.6 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/20.0.1090.0 Safari/536.6');

$serverOutput = curl_exec($ch);

curl_close ($ch);
echo $serverOutput;
```

I get now the response `{"error":"invalid_client"}` from the apple server. What am I doing wrong? Could it be that I'm generating the JWT token wrong?

Comment: Not a very constructive suggestion, but have you tried using an existing JWT token  library instead of generating yourself? Maybe there's something wrong in your JWT token generate process.

Comment: I found this https://developer.okta.com/blog/2019/06/04/what-the-heck-is-sign-in-with-apple and it is working for me

Comment: @hanashi Are you sure you verified your domain name with Apple?

Comment: I didn't verify my domain but still getting it working with nodejs!!
Here is the node script: https://gist.github.com/MustafaMagdi/ea27843af0228fb5221e0030b1d28f8d

Comment: where did you get this algo for `encode` function?

Comment: There is a typo: $payloads should be $payload, but still not working...

Comment: From Apple docs: "Some JWT libraries don’t support elliptic curve methods, so make sure yours does before you start trying this out.". I think this is a reason.

Comment: I am following "https://developer.okta.com/blog/2019/06/04/what-the-heck-is-sign-in-with-apple" this article for apple signing and for client secret I am using the same method as you used. each time I am getting `Invalid_client` issue. what is the solution?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem for me was that I forgot to verify my domain under the Service Id section of the Apple dev portal.

You need to download the key they give you, and upload it to:
https://example.com/.well-known/apple-developer-domain-association.txt

The website doesn't verify automatically, you have to click the verify button and get a green tick next to the domain to be sure. After this, I had no more `invalid_client` issues.

[image]

### Update 2020.07

As the flow was changed, you just have to add the Domain and the Communication Email to:

**`Certificates, Identifiers & Profiles > More > Configure`**

Comment: hmm, I don't see this anymore - perhaps they've changed it recently

Comment: Feed free to write an updated answer, or change my answer

Answer (score 3):

I had this error several times. Here are the causes I could find:

- Improper Domain Verification and invalid redirect_uri
- Client ID is not correct: your client ID could be incorrect.
- JWT encoder is not working properly: maybe it doesn't support the ES256 algorithm?
- Request type: for /auth/authorize, you need to use x-www-form-urlencode, oherwise you get `invalid_client` errors.

When I solved these problems, I started to get `invalid_grant` error. Here were the steps I had been doing:

- I created client_secret via JWT
- I navigated to `https://appleid.apple.com/auth/authorize?response_type=code&state=abcdefg&client_id=com.company.apple-sign-in-abcd&scope=openid&redirect_uri=https://app.com/redirect_uri` manually on web browser,
- authorized
- it redirected back to backend url (which gave 404 because it was not deployed yet).
- I copied the code argument in the url bar when
- With the copied `code`, I POSTeed the `https://appleid.apple.com/auth/token` 
  endpoint with x-www-form-urlencoded arguments:

  - code
  - client_id
  - client_secret
  - redirect_uri
  - grant_type="authorization_code"

If you lose a few seconds, `code` gets invalidated and you'll get `invalid_grant` 
error. If you copy and paste immediately within second, you'll get your response:

```
{
    "access_token": "abcdefg",
    "token_type": "Bearer",
    "expires_in": 3600,
    "refresh_token": "abcdefg",
    "id_token": "abcdefghijklmnopqrstu"
}
```

The next step would be decoding id_token with Apple's public key.

Comment: I am developing apple sign in for iOs App, I don't need `request_uri`. Do I need `request_uri`? Does apple provide any hook on this URL?

Comment: (as far as I remember) request_uri should be only for web logins. For iOS app, you don't need that. You need to submit the response you get from Apple to the backend and get the user authenticated on backend (by contacting Apple). With backend's approval to iOS app (by sending user profile), you can get the user logged in.

Comment: Earlier I was having an issue 'invalid_client' which is fixed now. I think my JWT code i.e. client secret wasn't matching. I have resolved it now. I started getting 'id_token' from apple, but after 1-2 times I am starting to get an `invalid_grant` issue now. I think everything is fine from the server end and there could be an issue with App auth code or permissions. I am doomed on this point and not able to move forward.

Answer (score 1):

I made a little package to generate apple client secret in php, based on jwt-framework:
https://github.com/kissdigital-com/apple-sign-in-client-secret-generator

Comment: I needed the solution for PHP5.6

Comment: If someone needs help. https://github.com/firebase/php-jwt/issues/70#issuecomment-714429232

Answer (score 1):

The `{"error":"invalid_client"}` message could be related to an invalid signature generated by the openssl_sign function. The ES256 algorithm must be used in order to sign the JWT and the generated signature should be the concatenation of two unsigned integers, denoted as R and S. It turns out that openssl_sign function generates a DER-encoded ASN.1 signature which is not correct for Apple (see [here](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/123723)).

So the solution is to convert the DER-encoded ASN.1 signature generated by openSSL into a simple concatenation of the R and S values.

This can be done by using the following function:

```
/**
 * @param string $der
 * @param int    $partLength
 *
 * @return string
 */
public static function fromDER(string $der, int $partLength)
{
    $hex = unpack('H*', $der)[1];
    if ('30' !== mb_substr($hex, 0, 2, '8bit')) { // SEQUENCE
        throw new \RuntimeException();
    }
    if ('81' === mb_substr($hex, 2, 2, '8bit')) { // LENGTH > 128
        $hex = mb_substr($hex, 6, null, '8bit');
    } else {
        $hex = mb_substr($hex, 4, null, '8bit');
    }
    if ('02' !== mb_substr($hex, 0, 2, '8bit')) { // INTEGER
        throw new \RuntimeException();
    }
    $Rl = hexdec(mb_substr($hex, 2, 2, '8bit'));
    $R = self::retrievePositiveInteger(mb_substr($hex, 4, $Rl * 2, '8bit'));
    $R = str_pad($R, $partLength, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT);
    $hex = mb_substr($hex, 4 + $Rl * 2, null, '8bit');
    if ('02' !== mb_substr($hex, 0, 2, '8bit')) { // INTEGER
        throw new \RuntimeException();
    }
    $Sl = hexdec(mb_substr($hex, 2, 2, '8bit'));
    $S = self::retrievePositiveInteger(mb_substr($hex, 4, $Sl * 2, '8bit'));
    $S = str_pad($S, $partLength, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT);
    return pack('H*', $R.$S);
}
/**
 * @param string $data
 *
 * @return string
 */
private static function preparePositiveInteger(string $data)
{
    if (mb_substr($data, 0, 2, '8bit') > '7f') {
        return '00'.$data;
    }
    while ('00' === mb_substr($data, 0, 2, '8bit') && mb_substr($data, 2, 2, '8bit') <= '7f') {
        $data = mb_substr($data, 2, null, '8bit');
    }
    return $data;
}
/**
 * @param string $data
 *
 * @return string
 */
private static function retrievePositiveInteger(string $data)
{
    while ('00' === mb_substr($data, 0, 2, '8bit') && mb_substr($data, 2, 2, '8bit') > '7f') {
        $data = mb_substr($data, 2, null, '8bit');
    }
    return $data;
}
```

which can be found in [this](https://github.com/web-token/jwt-framework/blob/v1.1/src/Component/Core/Util/ECSignature.php) library. More details here [Apple Sign In, sign JWT for authentication using PHP and openSSL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59737488/apple-sign-in-sign-jwt-for-authentication-using-php-and-openssl)

Answer (score 0):

You can use a library to handle [Apple sign-in SDK](https://github.com/AzimoLabs/apple-sign-in-php-sdk). Unfortunately, it supports PHP 7+ only