# How to exchange an Apple authorization code for an access token?

Tags: php, oauth-2.0, jwt, apple-sign-in

I am having a hard time figuring out how to use the sign in with Apple. The documentation is terrible and failed responses leaves us clueless. The article of Aaron Parecki (https://developer.okta.com/blog/2019/06/04/what-the-heck-is-sign-in-with-apple) does help a little, but I seem stuck now.

At first, I generate a login URL with /auth/authorize like so:

```php
$_SESSION['state'] = bin2hex(openssl_random_pseudo_bytes(16));

return 'https://appleid.apple.com/auth/authorize?' . http_build_query([
  'response_type' => 'code',
  'response_mode' => 'form_post',
  'client_id' => 'com.my.service.id',
  'redirect_uri' => 'https://my.app/redirect'),
  'state' => $_SESSION['state'],
  'scope' => 'name email',
]);
```

After struggling with the domain verification and return URLs, this brings me to the Apple login page and returns to my redirect_uri after succesfull login. Then, I need to authorize the token which I execute using Guzzle:

```php
$response = (new Client)->request('POST', 'https://appleid.apple.com/auth/token', [
  RequestOptions::FORM_PARAMS => [
    'grant_type' => 'authorization_code',
    'code' => $_POST['code'],
    'redirect_uri' => 'https://my.app/redirect',
    'client_id' => 'com.my.service.id',
    'client_secret' => $this->getClientSecret(),
  ],
  RequestOptions::HEADERS => [
    'Accept' => 'application/json'
  ]
]);

return json_decode($response, true);
```

The client secret is generated using Firebase php-jwt (https://github.com/firebase/php-jwt) and is valid through jwt.io:

```php
$key = openssl_pkey_get_private('file://certificate.p8');

return JWT::encode([
  'iss' => 'APPLETEAMID',
  'iat' => time(),
  'exp' => time() + 3600,
  'aud' => 'https://appleid.apple.com',
  'sub' => 'com.my.service.id',
], $key, 'ES256', 'certificate-id');
```

However, executing the token request to Apple returns a 400 error with the message 'invalid_client'. I cannot figure out if my client-id/secret is wrong or the code from the redirect is invalid. Can someone point me in the right direction?

EDIT:
Please note that I override the JWT class, allowing ES256 to be used. For more information, check [this open pull request](https://github.com/firebase/php-jwt/pull/239).

Comment: Does that maybe help? https://stackoverflow.com/a/57622747/2412335

Comment: @digijay I'm afraid not. Our domain was already verified.

Comment: I am indeed assuming that the code you are sending is invalid. How are you retrieving the code that you receive back from the authorization endpoint?

Comment: When you have your formed redirect url containing the code (so basically what your function returns), you can then perform a get on that url ($code = $_GET['code'];) to extract the code. That might be what you are doing now, but since it is not mentioned above, I figured I'd mention it.

Comment: @Axelle The redirect-URL after signing in is called as a POST-request from Apple, containing both the code and the state. Please see the second code block, where I retrieve the code from $_POST and use it in my token request to Apple.

Comment: Are you sure you should be using `JWT` at all? Taking a look at OAuth 2.0 Spec, it suggests HTTP `Basic` authentication where JWT uses `Bearer` token authentication; and both go onto header by the way.

See: https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6749#section-2.3.1

Comment: In my case I decided to completely drop php-jwt because the secret generated was not accettable for Apple. I found a way to generate a proper secret directly using openssl and converting the result. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59737488/apple-sign-in-invalid-client-sign-jwt-for-authentication-using-php-and-openss for details

Answer (score -4):

Based on what you said, and what [Apple](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/signinwithapplerestapi/authenticating_users_with_sign_in_with_apple) said in its documentation, I think you mistook Apple's `Identity token` with `Client Secret`.

Apple's `Identity Token` is a `JWT` token that uniquely identifies a user and is a layer of security "above" the existing OAuth 2.0 framework.

When you register/verify your client within an authorization server, based on the [RFC 6749 - The OAuth 2.0 Authorization Framework](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-2.3), you most probably receive a secret from the authorisation server which is your client's secret (namely, a password for your server at `com.my.service.id`) to be used in EVERY request from obtaining tokens to using identities to retrieve resources. The suggested method to use this `client_id/client_secret` pair is `HTTP Basic Authentication` method, and using a POST parameter is discouraged.

> The authorization server MUST support the HTTP Basic
> authentication scheme for authenticating clients that were issued a
> client password.

> ...

> Including the client credentials in the request-body using the two
> parameters is NOT RECOMMENDED and SHOULD be limited to clients unable
> to directly utilize the HTTP Basic authentication scheme (or other
> password-based HTTP authentication schemes).  The parameters can only
> be transmitted in the request-body and MUST NOT be included in the
> request URI.

You will receive the user's `Identity Token` in a form of JWT token and you should provide THAT exactly and not tampered with, for this token is issued by Apple itself. You may, however, inspect the payload (see [JWT Introduction at jwt.io](https://jwt.io/introduction/)) to know about the validity (`iat + exp`) of `Identity Token`. You should not generate an `Identity Token` unless you are coding for Apple's Authorization Team.

In the end, I cannot stress enough to read the OAuth spec thoroughly and remember that `Identity Token` is Apple's way of sending you a user's ID, but client_id and client_secret are something defined in OAuth spec.

Comment: Unfortunately, that is not the flow how "Sign in with Apple" works as it does not follow OAuth2 precisely. The redirect returns an authorization code (not the identity token), which should be exchanged for an access token. This request to /auth/token should be signed with the app client secret, which is generated with JWT. Please check the article of Aaron Parecki in my original question, where the flow is described step by step.