# Sign in with Apple = invalid_client

Tags: php, ios, jwt, apple-sign-in

I'm facing a very bad issue because I read so many guides and tutorials and nothing works.

The result is always the same: `{"error":"invalid_client"}`

I get the code, identityToken and everything I need - except the call to https://appleid.apple.com/auth/token - because of invalid_client.

Here is my url for getting the code.

https://appleid.apple.com/auth/authorize?response_type=code&client_id=org.example.service&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fexample.org

So then I have the default workflow.
And after accepting / loggin in I will be redirected to my page.

https://example.org/?code=a277243e2ec324fb09ba1c3333a8e6576.0.abcde.u4xiTDP2qHXoNEaxrcrIGx

(When I'm using the JavaScript API I'll get other informations like state, code and id_token. I already tried it with the "code" there, too.)

Back to the main function.

This is my request for Apple.

```
'client_id' => 'org.example.service',  
'client_secret' => JWT-Data encoded (OPENSSL_ALGO_SHA256) see below  
'grant_type' => 'authorization_code',  
'code' => 'a277243e2ec324fb09ba1c3333a8e6576.0.abcde.u4xiTDP2qHXoNEaxrcrIGx'
```

**JWT Header:**

```
{
  "alg": "ES256",
  "kid": "1ABC2345DE"
}
```

**JWT Payload:**

```
{
  "iss": "1A234BCD56",
  "iat": 1571269964,
  "exp": 1571273564,
  "aud": "https://appleid.apple.com",
  "sub": "org.example.service"
}
```

**Response:**

```
{  
  "error": "invalid_client"  
}
```

The useless error message of the world.

I dont know why the client should be invalid.

I have a key in https://developer.apple.com/account/resources/authkeys/list with downloaded file name AuthKey_1ABC2345DE.p8. (means 1ABC2345DE is my key id)

Then I have a native iOS app with identifier "org.example" and a service with identifier "org.example.service".

Its not working with both ids and mixed different things.

Nothing. invalid_client.

Can anyone help me please? I'm sitting here for hours and getting only invalid_client

My testing page:

```html
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://appleid.cdn-apple.com/appleauth/static/jsapi/appleid/1/en_US/appleid.auth.js"></script>
<div id="appleid-signin" data-color="black" data-border="true" data-type="sign in" data-width="330px" data-height="100px"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    AppleID.auth.init({
        clientId : 'org.example.service',
        scope : 'email',
        redirectURI: 'https://example.org',
        state : 'EN'
    });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

And PHP:

```php
<?php
// index.php

// function by https://stackoverflow.com/q/56459075/1362858
function encode($data) {
    $encoded = strtr(base64_encode($data), '+/', '-_');
    return rtrim($encoded, '=');
}

// function by https://stackoverflow.com/q/56459075/1362858
function generateJWT($kid, $iss, $sub, $key) {
    $header = [
        'alg' => 'ES256',
        'kid' => $kid
    ];
    $body = [
        'iss' => $iss,
        'iat' => time(),
        'exp' => time() + 3600,
        'aud' => 'https://appleid.apple.com',
        'sub' => $sub
    ];

    $privKey = openssl_pkey_get_private($key);
    if (!$privKey) return false;

    $payload = encode(json_encode($header)).'.'.encode(json_encode($body));
    $signature = '';
    $success = openssl_sign($payload, $signature, $privKey, OPENSSL_ALGO_SHA256);
    if (!$success) return false;

    return $payload.'.'.encode($signature);
}

$client_id = 'org.example.service';
$data = [
    'client_id' => $client_id,
    'client_secret' => generateJWT('1ABC2345DE', '1A234BCD56', $client_id, file_get_contents('AuthKey_1ABC2345DE.p8')),
    'code' => 'a277243e2ec324fb09ba1c3333a8e6576.0.abcde.u4xiTDP2qHXoNEaxrcrIGx',
    'grant_type' => 'authorization_code'
];
$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://appleid.apple.com/auth/token');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

$serverOutput = curl_exec($ch);

curl_close ($ch);

/**
 * {"error":"invalid_client"}
 */
var_dump($serverOutput);
```

Comment: I don't think `client_id` is the same as your iOS app's bundle ID, as "Sign in with Apple" is intended to also be available to non-app websites.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem was this special encryption.
In this blog they use PHP for everything except the client_secret generation.
https://developer.okta.com/blog/2019/06/04/what-the-heck-is-sign-in-with-apple

And in the text the author explains this sentence:

```
Some JWT libraries don’t support elliptic curve methods, so make sure yours does before you start trying this out.
```

Now it's working fine with exactly the code in the top - only replaced the client_secret generation.

Comment: Adding some details for those who are interested: the {"error":"invalid_client"} message could be related to an invalid signature generated by the openssl_sign function. The ES256 algorithm must be used in order to sign the JWT and the generated signature should be the concatenation of two unsigned integers, denoted as R and S. It turns out that openssl_sign function generates a DER-encoded ASN.1 signature which is not correct for Apple. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59737488/apple-sign-in-invalid-client-sign-jwt-for-authentication-using-php-and-openss/59842760#59842760 for details

Comment: Can you please add the solution here for others?

Answer (score 2):

well, I faced with this error "invalid_client" and just discovered, that all credentials were changed in https://developer.apple.com/account/resources/identifiers/serviceId . I think, because of changing of our legal entity (as account holder). So just check your web app ID and .p8 key, is it exist.

p.s. interesting, I been here, in this question, about a year ago, and it helped me as described above (JWT ES256 algo). And now, I hope, I'll help someone with another solution :-)

Answer (score 1):

We just had the same issue and the solution was to change the request content type from `multipart/form-data` to `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`.

So make sure that you post in the correct format else, Apple in their infinite wisdom to be different than everybody else, will refuse your request with this amazingly detailed error message...

Comment: This fixed it for me. Thank you so much! Incredible that this is documented absolutely nowhere, yay Apple....

Answer (score 0):

Be careful because of this `invalid_client` error could be misleading (as always Apple's error messages)

```
$postParams = array(
    'code' => ...,
    'client_id' => ...,
    'client_secret' => ...,
    'grant_type' => 'authorization_code',
    'redirect_uri' => ...,
);

$curl = curl_init('https://appleid.apple.com/auth/token');

// never pass params as just array for apple without stringifying via http_build_query()
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($postParams));
```

When you will use just `curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postParams);` it is valid POST request but another type than Apple expects but lazy apple developers are not able to provide error that this type of POST request is unsupported.